# typeorm test migration scripts before deployment

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS application with TypeORM that is deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Everytime when I'm doing changes to the database schema I'm creating a migration script as usual and then deploy my application with the `migrationsRun` property set to `true` in order for the migrations to automatically run when I make the deployment. However, because of existing data or other conflicts this nearly almost fails causing the entire deployment to fail.

I have been researching about best practices for production deployments with TypeORM but couldn't find any detailed guide. I specifically want to know how I can test my migration script without actually applying it to my schema. Hence, I could then debug my SQL queries before I make the actual deployment to ensure that my deployment will succeed. I'm of course also open for new suggestions since I just want to know what is the best and easiest way to handle schema updates together with application deployments.